# Trying to read a binary file for 4-byte unsigned integers and convert to volts

Tags: c++

I have some data recorded from an experiment, saved as binary files. A number of samples of voltage was recorded, and I'm told each sample is the 4 byte unsigned integer (unsigned integer) in the range 0 to 0xFFFFFF.
So, I am trying to read in the binary files in C++, perform the calculation that converts the binary data into volts, and write those values into a .csv file (from which I can import it into my analysis software).

Problem:
I tried using fread() to get the binary into an array named 'buffer'. It compiles without giving me an error, but the size of the array changes somewhere along to four times its original size, and the program itself crashes. It writes the same value repeatedly to the .csv file.
Am I using fread() correctly?

What I tried (in [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), using a [Borland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland) compiler):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    FILE * pFile;
    int buffer[30000];

    pFile = fopen ("00001001.e01", "rb");

    fread(buffer, 4, 30000, pFile); // Copy the file into the buffer:

    int buffsize = sizeof(buffer);
    cout << buffsize; //How big is the buffer?    It's 120000 now (error)

    //Open .csv file
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("test.csv");

    /* Loop to calculate voltage V[i] to V[n]*/
    int volts[30000];

    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++)
    {
        volts[i] = 1.6 * (buffer[i] - 0x7FFFFF) / 0x7FFFFF;
        outFile << volts[i] << ";" << endl;    /* To write each calculated value to the .csv file.*/
    }; //Error - now writes 30000 values that are all same value - "817'

    // Terminate
    fclose (pFile);
    free (buffer);
    outFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `sizeof` knows nothing about the data you read, it just tells you the size of buffer in bytes, which is `30000*sizeof(int)`, which in your case (32 bit `int`) it's 120000 bytes;
- since `sizeof` tells the size in bytes of the array (and not in number of elements), the condition of your `for` is wrong, it should be `i<totElems`, where `totElems` contain the total number of elements;
- buffer should be of type `unsigned int` or, better, of type `uint32_t` (`unsigned int` is not guaranteed to be 4 byte);
- if you want to store a floating-point value in `volts`, you have to make that array of type `float` or `double`; but actually, you don't need the `volts` array at all - you can just write the output of the calculation to `outFile`, without storing it anywhere;
- `endl` will uselessly slow down your program by performing unnecessary buffer flushes; just do `<<'\n'`;
- `free(buffer)` is completely wrong; `free` is used only for memory that has been dynamically allocated using `malloc` & friends, a local array like `buffer` or `volts` is freed automatically at the end of the function;
- you are intermixing C (`fopen` & co.) and C++ (`fstream` & co.) stuff (also, you are including several POSIX headers that aren't actually used); avoid this, either write in C or C++.

All this if you know in advance that the number of elements is 30000; if this is not the case, you have different ways to approach the problem:

- determine the number of elements (go at the end of the file with `fseek`, get the position with `ftell`, divide by element size, get back to the beginning of the file), allocate enough memory for them all, read them all as you did and proceed as you already did; typically a bad idea, you waste a lot of memory for nothing;
- on the other side, the easiest way is actually to get rid of the array; read a *single* value from the input file, calculate the converted value, write it to the output file; go on with the next; terminate the loop when there's no more data (`feof(pFile)` returns a nonzero value);
- you may obtain some performance improvements by reading data in big chunks, but, unless you are chumping very big files, if your knowledge of C and C++ is limited I would avoid it.

So, my tip is: stick with the second method.

Summing it all up, you could end up with something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream is("inputfile.dat", std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream os("output.csv");
    uint32_t i;
    while(is.read((char *)&i, sizeof(i))) 
        os<<1.6*(i-0x7fffff)/0x7fffff<<";\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Remarks:

- if your compiler doesn't supply `uint32_t` you should remove the `<stdint.h>` row and use `unsigned int` instead of `uint32_t`, maybe adding an `assert(sizeof(unsigned int)==4)`;
- if you have to process more than one file, you should probably make the input and output file command line parameters; use `argv` for that.

Comment: Additionally: Your program quite likely crashes because you're doing a `free` on `buffer`, which is a stack variable.  Remove the call to `free`.  Also, why are you using the C runtime library `fopen` and friends for input but C++ `ofstream` for output?  Pick C or C++ and be consistent.

Comment: Elements of `buffer` should be `uint_least32_t`.

Comment: @Casey: no, they need to be `uint32_t`; "least" won't do, since we are reading from file the binary representation of a very specific type (probably a 32 bit little endian unsigned integer).

Comment: MatteoItalia your suggestion works perfectly, and looks extremely elegant compared to my hulking Franken-code. Thanks for explaining the details of your corrections and for your tips, (because I will very likely be doing similar in the near future and I will probably not know the number of elements in advance) Much appreciated!
@CareyGregory and Casey, thanks for your suggestions too. C++ seems much more efficient.

Comment: @user3089109 actually, there was a classic mistake in my read loop, that results in outputting the last number twice. Now it's corrected, you should probably re-process your files.